# CodeIgniter: no direct script access allowed

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have a Lumen (Laravel) project inside my CodeIgniter project as a subdirectory, when I am trying to access the Lumen project, CodeIgniter gives me this message:

> "no direct script access allowed"

the hosting folder is: /hosting/instances/1111/my-codeigniter-app

then the structure inside the application is as follow:

- application
- files
- modules
- system
- lumen-api
- etc...

and here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /hosting/instances/1111

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^files.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /lumen-api/^(.*)$
    RewriteRule /lumen-api/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

in the lumen-api I have this prefix for the routing `v2/api`, so an example for the login route should be as follow:

https://www.mywebsite.com/hosting/instances/1111/my-codeigniter-app/lumen-api/v2/api/login

when I hit this URL it will always give me 'no direct access allowed'.

Comment: Why are you trying to use 2 separate PHP frameworks? I'm not surprised you are having issues doing this lol

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton LOL, it's a legacy project dude

Comment: Hey, I'm not bashing you, I was just wondering why you'd need to do that lol

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with your `.htaccess` file or the structure of the application folder. Each CodeIgniter file, except for the file initiating CodeIgniter, usually starts with the lines:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
   exit('No direct script access is allowed');
}
```

This stops unwanted users accessing your files.

In your case, because of the other framework, you are probably not initialising CodeIgniter properly. Normally `BASEPATH` is defined in the `public/index.php` file that starts CodeIgniter.

`BASEPATH` is a reserved constant in CodeIgniter that defines where the CodeIgniter system is installed. The system folder is separate to the application folder as multiple applications can share the same CodeIgniter system, without having to install the framework each time.

It sound like you have to find a way to initialise CodeIgniter from within your other framework. Have a look at a getting started with CodeIgniter tutorial, specifically focusing on how to set up the main `index.php` file.

Some background information:

- You can see all the reserved constants here: https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/reserved_names.html
- There is more chat about `if (!defined('BASEPATH'))` on the CodeIgniter forums: https://forum.codeigniter.com/post-348729.html
- `index.php` can be renamed  but it will be in the a public folder and probably not in the application folder. It defines the location of the system folder, application folder, development environment etc. It then processes a variety of things before starting the framework with  `require_once BASEPATH . 'core/CodeIgniter.php';` as its last line of code. There is a lot of chat online about how to hide `index.php` in the URL, which makes finding other information about it difficult. This is where `.htaccess` often gets mentioned in relation to CodeIgniter.